# How to find the time elapsed in a second order reaction given the final concentration?

Tags: kinetics

This is an example in my textbook that I am trying to figure out

$$1/[\ce{A}] = 1/[\ce{A}]_0 + kt$$

In this case:
\begin{align}
[\ce{A}] &= \pu{4.62E-2 M}\\  
[\ce{A}]_0 &= \pu{0.217 M}\\  
k &= \pu{0.540 M-1 s-1}
\end{align}

so I get this
$$1/(\pu{4.62E-2 M}) = 1/(\pu{0.217 M}) + (\pu{0.540 M-1 s-1})(t).$$

The answer should be $\pu{31.5 s}$.

I can’t get this answer I must be missing something
in the order that it should be.

Comment: What is the answer you get, then?

Comment: When you manipulate the equation to solve for t you'll want to subtract 1/[A]0 from 1/[A] and then divide by k.

Comment: It must be a math error.  Show us the next step in your calculation please.

Comment: ((1/0.0462) - (1/0.217)) / 0.540 = 31.5 s

Answer (score 2):

- Solving the equation

\begin{align}
  \frac{1}{[A]_t} &= \frac{1}{[A]_0} + k \cdot t\\
  \frac{1}{[A]_t} - \frac{1}{[A]_0} &= k \cdot t\\
  \frac{1}{[0.0462 \ M]_t} - \frac{1}{[0.217 \ M]_0} &= 0.540 \ M^{-1} \cdot s^{−1} \cdot t\\
  21.64 \ M^{-1} - 4.61 \ M^{-1} &= 0.540 \ M^{-1} \cdot s^{−1} \cdot t\\
  17.03 \ {\color{red}{M^{-1}}} &= 0.540 \ \color{red}{M^{-1}} \cdot s^{−1} \cdot t\\
\\ \text{Molarity is simplified} \\ \\
  \frac{17.03}{0.540\ s^{-1}} &=t\\ \\
  \pu{31.53 s} &= t
\end{align}

- Unsig Wxmaxima (or Maple)
  [image]

Comment: Please always carry the units in every step.

Comment: I have added the units of measurement. Thanks a lot